# Can't get folder info by it's ID (Dropbox Api v2)

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a problem with getting folder info by it's shared link / ID.

I have two users - the system user who calls the Dropbox API (ex. user A) and a regular user (ex. user B). I have a folder created by user B, user A is added to the members of this folder as owner. I have a link to this folder created by user B.

From user A through the Dropbox API calls I want to receive metadata of this folder, incl. its path, to be able to work with this folder (add / remove files, links, users, etc.).

To achieve this I:

1. Get folder link metadata (incl. folder ID like "id:a4ayc_80_OEAAAAAAAAAXz") using [sharing/get_shared_link_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_metadata).
2. Get folder metadata using [files/get_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_metadata) with recieved folder ID as "path" parameter but in response I get the error "path/not_found/".

Why can't my system user A get information on the folder having its ID and being its member (owner)?